# Clustering network of keyword concurrence with Networkx and the "Force Atlas" or "Sampson" algorithm

Tags: python, networkx

I have a large network to visualize with NetworkX. The matrix for network visualization is a co-occurrence of keywords in CSV format. I run the below commands and see the graph. My problem is with clustering the network. I would appreciate it if let me know how I can cluster based on the "Force Atlas" or "Sampson" algorithm. I've tried for the Force Atlas but I had difficulty in installing "pygraphviz" in windows.

```
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


input_data = pd.read_csv('Matrix.csv', index_col=0)
G = nx.DiGraph(input_data.values)
nx.draw(G)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a position to the draw command like this:

```
nx.draw(G, pos=nx.spring_layout(G))
```

This will use the Fruchterman-Reingold force-directed algorithm to compute the position of the nodes. There are more layouts to explore: https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/drawing.html

If I recal correctly Gephi (https://gephi.org/) has an implementation of the Force Atlas layout implemented. Check it out if your goal is to plot large networks.

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately, there are some new implementations of Force Atlas in Python:

https://pypi.org/project/ForceAtlas2/
https://github.com/bosiakov/fa2l

And they worked very well with Networkx.